# Getting strange error when searching by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to make report page, on which user will choose start and end date and push buttopn report. Then hidden div became visible.


My search isn't on partial.

I am using  jquery_datepicker so here is my code from view:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "financial_reports", :action => "index", :method => "post")%>
  <%= datepicker_input "financial_report","start_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy" %>
  <%= datepicker_input "financial_report","end_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy" %>
 <%=  submit_tag "Run Report"%>
<% end %>
```

Here is my code from controller:

```
  def search
   @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.search(params[:start_date], params[:end_date]
  render :index
  end
```

In my Model:

```
def self.search(from,to)
  find(:all, :conditions => [ "BETWEEN ? AND ?", from, to])
 end
```

And it gives me error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FinancialReportsController#search 
    SELECT `financial_reports`.* FROM `financial_reports`  WHERE `financial_reports`.`user_id` = 67 AND (BETWEEN NULL AND NULL)
```

and below this:

```
     Parameters:

  {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AMobLLRV3aAlNn6b4Au+1nRP2AN1TLQcBCytBXhDA/g=",
  "type"=>"",
   "financial_report"=>{"start_date"=>"05/08/2012",
      "end_date"=>"11/08/2012"},
    "commit"=>"Run Report",
   "method"=>"post"}
```

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both parameters are set at all times, you can use:

`@financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where(:created_at => ((params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date))`

If that's not the case, you could (for example) do this:

```
@financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports

if params[:start_date].present?
  @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where("created_at >= ?", params[:start_date])
end

if params[:end_date].present?
  @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where("created_at <= ?", params[:end_date])
end
```

You will probably want to encapsulate this in scopes.

Comment: `undefined method to_date for nil:NilClass` that is because my params are empty at this moment, yes ?

Comment: Maybe I should add search method ?